# Coq - return value of type which is equal to function return type

Tags: types, coq, typechecking

By some theorem we know that type `A` equals type `B`. How can I tell this to Coq compiler during type checking?

I want to implement a non-empty tree such that each node know its size:

```
Inductive Struct: positive -> Type :=
| Leaf : Struct 1%positive
| Inner: forall {n m}, Struct n -> Struct m -> Struct (n + m).
```

I want to create a function which generates a tree of a given size of logarithmic depth. E.g.

`7 -> 6 + 1 -> (3 + 3) + 1 -> ((2 + 1) + (2 + 1)) + 1 -> (((1 + 1) + 1) + ((1 + 1) + 1)) + 1`

```
Fixpoint nat2struct n : (Struct n) :=
  match n with
  | xH => Leaf
  | xO n => Inner (nat2struct n) (nat2struct n) 
  | xI n => Inner Leaf (Inner (nat2struct n) (nat2struct n))
  end.
```

However, I get the error:

> The term "Inner Leaf (Inner (nat2struct n0) (nat2struct n0))" has type "Struct (1 + (n0 + n0))" while it is expected to have type "Struct n0~1".

How can I fix this? We know that `(1 + n + n) = xI n`, but Coq doesn't. If I state this theorem before, it doesn't change anything:

```
Theorem nBy2p1: forall n, Pos.add 1%positive (n + n) = xI n. Proof. Admitted.
Hint Resolve nBy2p1.
```

Are there some hints for Coq to be aware of this theorem?

PS1: is this theorem already proved in standard library? I didn't find one.

PS2: I actually want to split more naturally: `7 -> 4 + 3 -> (2 + 2) + (2 + 1) -> ((1 + 1) + (1 + 1)) + ((1 + 1) + 1)`. Is it possible? I don't know how to write it so that Coq understands that the function converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When type-checking, Coq uses a weaker form of equality (sometimes called definitional,  judgemental, or computational equality). Unlike propositional equality (what "=" binds to by default), definitional equality is decidable. Coq can take any two terms and decide if one is convertible into the other. If propositional equality were allowed in type-checking, type-checking would no longer be decidable<sup>1</sup>.

To fix your problem (and it is a pretty big problem) you have a few options.

## Make `Struct` a record

I'll demonstrate the principle using lists. First, we have the notion of unsized lists.

```
Inductive UnsizedList (A: Type) :=
| unil
| ucons (a: A) (u: UnsizedList A).

Arguments unil [A], A.
Arguments ucons [A] a u, A a u.

Fixpoint length {A: Type} (u: UnsizedList A) :=
match u with
| unil => 0
| ucons _ u' => S (length u')
end.
```

We can also define a sized list, where every element of `SizedList A n` has length `n`.

```
Inductive SizedList (A: Type): nat -> Type :=
| snil: SizedList A 0
| scons {n: nat} (a: A) (u: SizedList A n): SizedList A (S n).
```

This definition runs into the exact same problem as yours. For example, if you want to show that concatenation is associative, you can't simply prove `concat (concat u v) w = concat u (concat v w)`, since the two sides of the equality have different types (`(i + j) + k` vs `i + (j + k)`). If we could simply tell Coq what size we expect the list to be, then prove it later, we could solve this. That's what this definition does, which packs together an `UnsizedList` with a proof that that list has the desired length.

```
Record SizedListPr (A: Type) (n: nat): Type := {
  list: UnsizedList A;
  list_len_eq: length list = n;
}.
```

Now we can have `concat (concat u v) w = concat u (concat v w)`; we just need to prove that both sides have length `(i + j) + k`.

## Use coercions

This approach can get pretty messy if you aren't careful, so it's not often the preferred approach.

Let me define a sort of coercion that maps elements of type `P x` to elements of type `P y` if `x = y`.<sup>2</sup>

```
Definition coercion {A: Type} (P: A -> Type) {x y: A} (p: x = y): P x -> P y :=
match p with
| eq_refl => fun t => t
end.
```

Here we use induction on the term `p: x = y`. The induction principle says, essentially, that if we can prove something when `x` and `y` are definitionally equal, then we can prove it when they're propositionaly equal.<sup>3</sup> When `P x` and `P y` are the same, we can just use the identity function.

Now, for example, the statement of associativity of concatenation for sized lists is `concat (concat u v) w = coercion (SizedList A) (add_assoc) (concat u (concat v w))`. So we coerce something of type `SizedList A (i + (j + k))` to something of type `SizedList A ((i + j) + k)` using the equality `add_assoc: i + (j + k) = (i + j) + k` (I've left out some parameters for readability).

---

What choice you make is up to you. A discussion of this problem and related problems, as well as some additional resolutions can be found at the *Certified Programming with Dependent Types* page [Equality](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Equality.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> See *extensional type theory* for a class of theories where this typically happens. [Martin Hofmann's thesis](http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/95/ECS-LFCS-95-327/) has an overview of the difference between intensional and extensional theories.

<sup>2</sup> If you're familiar with Homotopy Type Theory, this is `transport`.

<sup>3</sup> There are enough caveats on this statement that the differences between propositional and definitional equality still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on User's answer this is the solution I ended up with:

```
Inductive Struct: positive -> Type :=
| Leaf : Struct 1
| Inner : forall {lsize rsize size}
    (proof: Pos.add lsize rsize = size),
    (Struct lsize) -> (Struct rsize) -> Struct size.

Local Lemma nBy2: forall {n}, Pos.add n n = xO n.
Proof.
intros.
assert (Zpos (n + n) = Zpos (n~0)). { rewrite Pos2Z.inj_add. rewrite Z.add_diag. symmetry. apply Pos2Z.inj_xO. }
inversion H. auto.
Qed.

Local Lemma nBy2p1: forall {n}, Pos.add 1 (xO n) = xI n.
Proof.
intros. simpl.
assert (Zpos (1 + n~0) = Zpos (n~1)). { rewrite Pos2Z.inj_add. reflexivity. }
inversion H. auto.
Qed.

Fixpoint structCreate (size : positive) : (Struct size) :=
  match size with
  | xH => Leaf
  | xO n =>
    let child := structCreate n in
    Inner nBy2 child child
  | xI n => 
    let child := structCreate n in
    Inner nBy2p1 Leaf (Inner nBy2 child child)
  end.
```